# setAutoGrowCollectionLimit not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I try to set the default limit of collection binding by specifing the InitBinder.

```
@InitBinder
public void initListBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(1000);
}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    CustomDateEditor customDateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat,
            true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, true));
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "Date",
            customDateEditor);
}
```

Still my code return IndexOutOfBoundsException again. Exception:

> org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException : Invalid property 'list[256]' of bean class [com.AppController]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'list[256]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256 at

Could anybody explain this behavior? I am using Spring 4.

Comment: I think it's part of this issue which was just released with version 4.3.5. Take a look here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14888

Comment: @ndrone i am using version 4.0.4.RELEASE.